# Altitude Disappears from MKPlacemark

Tags: ios, objective-c, cllocation, mkreversegeocoder

So I have some code that gets the user's location from the phone as a `CLLocation`, then I do a reverse geocode on it. The problem is that the resulting `MKPlacemark` has `0` for altitude, despite the fact that the `CLLocation` had a value in the altitude field.

It makes sense that if I just ask for the address of some coordinates, I don't necessarily get altitude (as that would require topographic logic). Most of the questions on here suggest calling out to a topo service.

I am wondering why the reverse geocoder would not just preserve the altitude, and also asking people what their preferred solution has been to this problem. It's not like it's hard to figure out: I can pass the altitude in separately and then just jam it into my ultimate object (my own address class), but that's ugly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is indeed the state of these classes at this time. Probably a bug report with Apple is in order.